# HTML5 Video Progress Scrubbing click Function not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I've added this click function to change the time when you click on the progress bar for the video.

This worked in Chrome until I styled the progress bar - now it only works in Firefox. Consequently the buffer bar doesn't populate in Firefox.

http://nathanworking.github.io/html-video-page/

```
// Update video based on click
function seek(e) {
    var percent = e.offsetX / this.offsetWidth;
    video.currentTime = percent * video.duration;
    progress.value = percent / 100;
    // Update the button icon to 'Pause'
    playButton.className = "pause-button";
}
  progress.addEventListener("click", seek);
```

Is there another method for updating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offsetWidth of your progress bar (this.offsetWidth) is resulting in a zero value which is wreaking havoc with the calculation to determine the video's currentTime. You should add a position property of absolute to both your #progress and #buffer elements:

```
#progress,
#buffer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0.2em;
}
```

Please put that above your first #progress selector in your css and then remove top:0.2em; from the #buffer selector.